# Combine several planes, each with its own unique texture into one "model" and keep all of the textures in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh

In  Unity, I've created a "stack" of planes (programmatically) - each of which has an image on it. I want to be able to take the camera and zoom into the stack, and as it zooms through the stack of planes, see each of the images.

Imagine taking a camera through a Russian Matryoshka doll and seeing each of the smaller dolls as you progress through it.

It's also important to note that in my case, the stack of planes are not perfectly aligned in a stack, and so some of them will intersect slightly - I need to make sure they don't flicker.

I would like to combine these planes, each with its own image into a singular "model" (Mesh is probably the right terminology, but using this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6APzUgckV7U didn't work - it took all of my planes and simply converted it into a single plane; that being said, I was able combine these planes but it created a single object with a single material). This uses mesh combiners, but I'm not sure this is the right approach.

Here is some code I've written which takes all of the planes out of the `slicesHolder` and combines them into one "model." It then put that "model" inside of the `finalObject` but unfortunately, the "model" does not retain any of the materials (images) from the slices. And `slicesHolder` is destroyed.

```
Quaternion oldRot = slicesHolder.transform.rotation;
Vector3 oldPos = slicesHolder.transform.position;

finalObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity;
finalObject.transform.position = Vector3.zero;

MeshFilter[] meshFilters = slicesHolder.GetComponentsInChildren<MeshFilter>();

Debug.Log("Combining " + meshFilters.Length + " meshes");

Mesh finalMesh = new Mesh();
CombineInstance[] combiners = new CombineInstance[meshFilters.Length];

            for(int a = 0; a < meshFilters.Length; a++){
                //if(meshFilters[a].transform == transform)
                //continue;

                combiners[a].subMeshIndex = 0;
                combiners[a].mesh = meshFilters[a].sharedMesh;
                combiners[a].transform = meshFilters[a].transform.localToWorldMatrix;
            }

finalMesh.CombineMeshes(combiners);

finalObject.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().sharedMesh = finalMesh;
finalObject.transform.rotation = oldRot;
finalObject.transform.position = oldPos;

Destroy(slicesHolder);
finalObject.SetActive(true);
```

Is this the correct way of trying to create a singular "model" which has a "stack" of individual images so that I can zoom into this stack and see deeper into the model?

Answer (score 1):

## There is no effective way to do this

And the reason for that is the textures. Or more specifically the *materials.* Because each plane has a unique material instance there is no way to combine it with another plane. You're either going to end up with what you started with or you'll get a combined model using only *one* of the textures on each face.

You would need a way to map each of the desired textures onto a sprite sheet, create a new material with that sprite sheet, and then figure out what the UV offsets are to convert from one material to the sprite sheet material, assign the sprite sheet material to all the planes, *then* mesh-combine them.